# unable to create web_app button aiogram

Tags: python, web-applications, telegram, aiogram

Good afternoon, an update has recently been released in telegram and added web_app buttons. leading to the "site" in the telegram itself, the documentation says that you need to import the script to the page and create a button in the bot

html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

code for sending a message with a button:

```py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.types.web_app_info import WebAppInfo
await msg.reply("test", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="test", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://test_link"))))
```

Error:

```
Button_type_invalid
```

thanks in advance for your help)

**Update: you cannot send a message with a web_app type button in non-personal messages to the user. attempting to do so produces an error "Button_type_invalid"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, everything worked for me, although yesterday I also encountered this error, it's strange.
Run this code with your API token:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.types.web_app_info import WebAppInfo

API_TOKEN = 'your bot api token'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("test", 
reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="test", 
web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/891"))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```